# Docker + node.js: can't spawn phantomjs (ENOENT)

Tags: node.js, docker, phantomjs

I'm running a node.js application that uses the `html-pdf` module, which in turn relies on `phantomjs`, to generate PDF files from HTML.  The app runs withing a Docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

WORKDIR /mydirectory
# [omitted] git clone, npm install etc....

RUN npm install -g html-pdf --unsafe-perm
VOLUME /mydirectory

ENTRYPOINT ["node"]
```

Which builds an image just fine.

app.js

```
const witch = require('witch');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');
const phantomPath = witch('phantomjs-prebuilt', 'phantomjs');

function someFunction() {
  pdf.create('some html content', { phantomPath: `${this._phantomPath}` });
}

// ... and then some other stuff that eventually calls someFunction()
```

And then call `docker run <the image name> app.js`

When `someFunction` gets called, the following error message is thrown:

`Error: spawn /mydirectory/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs ENOENT`

This happens both when deploying the container on a cloud linux server or locally on my machine.

I have tried adding `RUN npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt --unsafe-perms` to the Dockerfile, to no avail (this makes docker build fail because the installation of `html-pdf` cannot validate the installation of `phantomjs`)

I'm also obviously not a fan of using the `--unsafe-perms` argument of npm install, so if anybody has a solution that allows bypassing that, it would be fantastic.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: so howd you solve this?

Answer (score 9):

This is what ended up working for me, in case this is helpful to anyone:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

WORKDIR /mydirectory
# [omitted] git clone, npm install etc....

ENV PHANTOMJS_VERSION=2.1.1
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache fontconfig curl curl-dev && \
    cd /tmp && curl -Ls https://github.com/dustinblackman/phantomized/releases/download/${PHANTOMJS_VERSION}/dockerized-phantomjs.tar.gz | tar xz && \
    cp -R lib lib64 / && \
    cp -R usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib && \
    cp -R usr/share /usr/share && \
    cp -R etc/fonts /etc && \
    curl -k -Ls https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-${PHANTOMJS_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 | tar -jxf - && \
    cp phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs

USER node
RUN npm install -g html-pdf

VOLUME /mydirectory

ENTRYPOINT ["node"]
```

Comment: PDF generated successfully but not able to see any text. only schema and background color and images are visible.

Comment: How would i include `npm install` to add other packages

Comment: You can remove the commands - `ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global` & `ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin` & `RUN npm install -g html-pdf` if that works for you. It worked for me also if I remove the commands that I mentioned. @O'DaneBrissett If you need to npm install packages you can place it anywhere before ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: A reference which also mentions about solving this issue - https://gist.github.com/vovimayhem/6437c2f03b654e392ccf3e9903eba6af

Comment: @Udhaya If you cannot see any text, its a issue with fonts not present in the docker image. Add this to docker file `RUN apk --update add ttf-ubuntu-font-family fontconfig && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`

Comment: @Udhaya Above link is broken, try this                                                                       
          RUN apk --update add ttf-freefont fontconfig && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, only workaround for me was to download and copy a phantom manualy. This is my example from docker file, it should by the last thing before EXPOSE comand. Btw I use a `node:10.15.3` image.

```
RUN wget -O /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
RUN mkdir /tmp/phantomjs && mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/
RUN tar xvjf /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C /tmp/phantomjs
RUN mv /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/* /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/
RUN rm -rf /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz && rm -rf /tmp/phantomjs
```

Don't forget to update your paths. It's only workaround, I didn't have time to figure it out yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it unfortunately did not work for me, but I will post what did the trick on my end below.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question in March 2021 and had the same issue dockerizing highcharts: it worked on my machine but failed on docker run (same spawn phantomjs error). In the end, the solution was to find a FROM node version that worked. This Dockerfile works using the latest Node docker image and almost latest highcharts npm version (always pick up specific npm versions):

```
FROM node:15.12.0

ENV ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE YES

# see available versions of highcharts at https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-export-server
RUN npm install highcharts-export-server@2.0.30 -g

EXPOSE 7801

# run the container using: docker run -p 7801:7801 -t CONTAINER_TAG
CMD [ "highcharts-export-server", "--enableServer", "1" ]
```